# OpenCV correct face color C++

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, colors

I´m making a small project in C++ using OpenCV and Dlib. This is a pipeline:

1. Load image with 2 faces

[image]

2. Detect both faces
3. Find face Landmarks using Dlib shape predictor
4. Create masks using these landmarks

[image]

5. Warp masks and images using both faces landmarks

[image]
[image]

6. Blend all images (original, and 2 warped)

[image]

7. Correct colors of switched faces

Has somebody an idea how could I correct colors of that switched faces to approximately match original face?

After using seamlessClone I get this result. The problem is that I can't accuratelly choose argument `center` for seamlessClone. I used this code to get centers

```
Moments m = moments((mask>=50), true);
Point center(m.m10/m.m00, m.m01/m.m00);
```

I get this result.

[image]

As you can see first face is aligned perfectly but second not :( On other images it is much worse.

Any Idea what point to use as center?

Comment: Check [seamless cloning](http://www.learnopencv.com/seamless-cloning-using-opencv-python-cpp/)

Comment: can you post USABLE images? aligned (warped), masks, and original images without any window border and without cropping and stuff (use imwrite function for example)?

Comment: http://www.learnopencv.com/face-swap-using-opencv-c-python/

Comment: Thanks a lot, seamlessClone is perfect. Only one problem I have with it is that I can't get argument `center` accurately. I tried using moments as described in this question - http://answers.opencv.org/question/460/finding-centroid-of-a-mask/. First face was aligned perfectly but second not. Picture up in my question.